# How to upload file and then send it to another server by Nodejs (expressjs)

Tags: http, node.js, express

1. User uses input(type="file") to upload file on server
2. `req.files.avatar` to access file on server side

How can I send this file (req.files.avatar) by HTTP POST method (name="avatar") to another server. I don't want to store it before sending.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your looking for is;

```
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy
```